# Observers not being triggered whe LiveData changes - Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, android-room, kotlin-coroutines, android-livedata, observers

I know this question has been asked a couple of times, but I have a funny situation here that I can't figure out.

I have a `database` with "TASKS" and, apart from the writing/updating methods, I'm calling the get method twice: one for getting the last created task, and another to select an specific task by ID

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM tasks_history_table ORDER BY taskId DESC LIMIT 1")
    suspend fun getCurrentTask(): Task2?

@Query("SELECT * from tasks_history_table WHERE  taskId = :key ")
    suspend fun get(key: Long): Task2?
```

Then in the `viewModel` I'm launching a `coroutine` for each time I call one of these methods.

This one for the last created Task:

```
private fun initializeCurrentTask(){
    viewModelScope.launch {
        _currentTask.value = getCurrentTaskFromDatabase()!!
    }
}
suspend fun getCurrentTaskFromDatabase(): Task2? {
    var currentTask = database.getCurrentTask()
    return currentTask
    }
```

And this one for the specific task

```
fun initializeSelectedTask(){
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _currentTask.value = getSelectedTaskFromDatabase(selectedTaskId.value!!)!!
        }
    }
    suspend fun getSelectedTaskFromDatabase(taskId: Long): Task2? {
        var currentTask = database.get(selectedTaskId.value!!)!!
        return currentTask
    }
```

So they are both pretty much the same, except for the parameter Id passed.

Then, I'm sending that data to the `Fragment` to update the UI, via `LiveData`

```
private val _currentTask = MutableLiveData<Task2>()
    val currentTask : LiveData<Task2>
        get() = _currentTask
```

And here the `observer`:

```
timerViewModel.currentTask.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
            updateUIText()
            updateCountdownUI()
            updateAnimation()
        }
```

Everytime I call the function to get the las saved task, the `observers` are called and everything works fine. But whenever I call the function to get a specific task by Id, the `observers` are not called.

I've set `Logs` all around and I've reached the conclusion that the `LiveData` is getting updated, but the `observer` is not triggered.

Here's the repo in case someone can have it a look. Thanks!!
https://github.com/arieldipietro/PomodoroTechnique

Comment: your repo is missing packages for example there is no package called database.

Comment: Sorry, should be working now @YunusDilber

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `FragmentTimer` and `FragmentHistory`, you have created `viewModel` instances using their respective `fragments` as owners, which makes them to observe `liveData` which are triggered by their instances only. So, now when you trigger a task from `FragmentHistory` it isn't get observed in `FragmentTimer`.

You need to use `SharedViewModel` for passing data between fragments, you have to create object of `TimerViewModel` using `activity` as its owner, then you would be able to observe from `FragmentTimer`. Pass `requireActivity()` as the owner in `ViewModelProvider`'s constructor.

```
timerViewModel = ViewModelProvider(requireActivity(), viewModelFactory)[TimerViewModel::class.java]
```

You can read more about it in this [codelab tutorial](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-training-shared-viewmodel#3).